# How to refresh a DrawerLayout after language change?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, locale

i was trying to localize my app with different languages everything works but the items on the drawer layout wont update to the new language unless the app is restarted heres the code i used to change the language.

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config =  new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
c.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

the variable `lang` being the language thats being set.

so is there any way i can refresh the drawer layout after the language is set?

Comment: try invalidating the view by calling view.invalidate().

Comment: No its the same...if you could come up with another solution please i am on a deadline

Comment: The last option is to recreate the activity.

Comment: call the onCreate(null)

Comment: I am trying to refresh the drawer from the onResume method of the activity...calling onCreate would raise an IllegalSatateException Already attached error

Comment: onResume calling is highly expensive. The best is to start the activity again with removing the previous one using finish().